# Why is my method don't append the csv-file?

Tags: java, android, android-7.0-nougat

I try to export the GPS-Data from my Android 7 smartphone to a .csv file for some time as long as isSaveCSV() is true.

```
public void saveCSVfile() {
    if (isSaveCSV()) {
        Long time = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
        String entry =time.toString()+","+lat+","+lon+"\n";
        if (csv_created==false) {
            csv_created=true;
            FILECOUNT++;
            NEWFILENAME = FILENAME+FILECOUNT+".csv";
            File myDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "tensorflow");
            csvfile = new File(myDir, NEWFILENAME);
            try {
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(csvfile);
                out.write( entry.getBytes() );
                out.close();
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                LOGGER.e(e, "Exception!");
            }
        }else {

            try {
                entry="TESTFORFOOSAKE";
               FileOutputStream out = openFileOutput(csvfile.getName(), Context.MODE_APPEND);
                out.write(entry.getBytes());
                out.close();
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                LOGGER.e(e, "Exception!");
            }
        }
    }else {
        csv_created=false;
    }
}
```

The file is always one row.. I never saw a double line file..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to append to an existing file, you should use the overloaded constructor that takes a boolean argument:

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(csvfile, true);
// Here ---------------------------------------------^
```